# Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error after firing this query.

```
select COUNT(*) 
from [DB1].dbo.Transaction(nolock) t 
join [DB2].dbo.visits (nolock) v 
on t.V_ID=v.V_ID 
where t.Ct_ID=11  
and t.Timestamp>'06-08-2015' 
and v.C_ID is null
```

Error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Comment: Try using `COUNT_BIG`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `COUNT_BIG` instead of `COUNT`.

Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Additionally, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) shows the limits for the different types of `INT`s.